# Why am I getting the error "getParentActivityIntent : badActivity name" after committing my Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-debugging

I am creating a simple `FragmentList` App, but for some reason I keep getting the error:

```
Log.e(TAG, "getParentActivityIntent: bad parentActivityName '" + parentName +
                    "' in manifest");
```

In my debugger in `Activity.java`

**This happens in my `MainActivity.java` file right after `.commit()`:**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.myContainer);

        if(fragment == null){
            fragment = new MyFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.myContainer, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyFragment.java file**:

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {
    List<Course> courses = new CourseData().courseArrayList();

    public MyFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.courselist_item, courses);

        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
 
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courselist_item, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**ArrayAdapter.java**:

```
public class ArrayAdapter extends android.widget.ArrayAdapter<Course> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Course> courses;

    public ArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, List<Course> courses) {
        super(context, resource, courses);
        this.context = context;
        this.courses = courses;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        Course course = courses.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courselist_item, null);


        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.course_image_id);
        imageView.setImageResource(course.getImageResourceId(context));

        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.course_name);
        textView.setText(course.getCourseName());

        return view;

    }
}
```

**Course.java:**

```
package com.krish.mylistfragmennt;

import android.content.Context;

public class Course {
    private String courseName;
    private String courseImage;

    public Course(String courseName, String courseImage) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseImage = courseImage;
    }

    public int getImageResourceId(Context context){
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(this.courseImage, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public String getCourseImage() {
        return courseImage;
    }

    public void setCourseImage(String courseImage) {
        this.courseImage = courseImage;
    }
}
```

**CourseData.java**:

```
public class CourseData {

    public String[] courseNames = {"First Course", "Second Course", "Third Course"};

    public ArrayList<Course> courseArrayList(){
        ArrayList<Course> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i< courseNames.length; i++){
            Course course = new Course(courseNames[i], courseNames[i].replace(" ", "").toLowerCase());
            list.add(course);

        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.krish.mylistfragmennt">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyListFragmennt">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in instantiating the adapter within `onCreate()` callback which is earlier than the fragment can access its activity with `getActivity()`.

So, try to transfer that to `onCreateView()` callback.

Also use `requireActivity()` as it's safer than `getActivity()`

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {
    List<Course> courses = new CourseData().courseArrayList();

    public MyFragment(){

    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courselist_item, container, false);

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(requireActivity(), R.layout.courselist_item, courses);

        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);   
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Zain. However, I'm still getting the error of bad parent activity name in manifest. Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: @CodingChap can you please post the entire logcat of the exception.

Comment: Also please share the maifest file

Comment: In logcat I'm getting a different error than debugger:  `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.krish.mylistfragmennt, PID: 25374
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080107 (com.krish.mylistfragmennt:id/myContainer) for fragment MyFragment{5374c21} (97892683-c9c4-40a7-9f65-f3d393bff245 id=0x7f080107)` I updated Manifest file in post

Comment: @CodingChap please remove `android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"` from the manifest file

Comment: Thanks. Tried that, still no luck.

Comment: Yes you're right .. the exception is different .. I think you passed a wrong layout in the fragment ... `R.layout.courselist_item` seems like it's for an adapter item isn't it >>> especially that it's passed to the adapter constructor

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed that to my_fragment.xml but I'm still getting the same fatal exception. I tried taking out the setContentView in MainActivity, but I'm not sure if that's right.

Comment: Hi! I have fixed it, thank you so much. I realized that I should change the setContentView to my_fragment since I want that xml file to display.

Comment: Hi @CodingChap I guess you mean the activity as `setContentView()` is for activities .. happy coding